# Solving a Nasty Matrix / Tensor Algebra Problem

Tags: matrix-equations

I need to solve the following:

$$
\sum_{i,c,d} x_{i,a} x_{i,b} x_{i,c} x_{i,d} W_{c,d} = \sum_{i} x_{i,a} x_{i,b} y_{i}
$$

for known x and y, and W is symmetric. It is safe to assume that the elements of x and y are completely random.

If I define

$$
A_{a,b,c,d} = \sum_{i} x_{i,a} x_{i,b} x_{i,c} x_{i,d}
$$

$$
B_{c,d} = \sum_{i} x_{i,a} x_{i,b} y_{i}
$$

and create auxiliary matrices

$$
W'_{M*a+b} = W_{a,b}
$$

$$
A'_{M*a+b,M*c+d} = A_{a,b,c,d}
$$

and

$$
B'_{M*c+d} = B_{c,d}
$$

I get the equation of the form

$$
\sum_{j} A'_{ij} W'_{j} = B'_{j}
$$

which suggests one can solve using

$$
W'_i = A'^{-1}_{ij} B'_j
$$

and converting back to the original W matrix. The issue arrises as A' is never invertable (for some reason?). Is there some symmetry of A' which means that it has 0 determinant, and can this be solved by removing the symmetric parts of A' to get A'' which has lower dimensionality? Supposing that M = 6, there are 126 unique elements of A and 21 of B and W. Is there a simple way of converting to different auxiliary matrices which have none of the degeneracy caused by the symmetry in the definitions of A and B?

Intuitively, there are 21 (6+5+4+3+2+1) unique equations and 21 uniquely determined variables so there should be a way to lift the degeneracy as the problem is exactly determined.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\A{{\large\cal A}}
\def\LR#1{\left( #1 \right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[ #1 \Big]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let's use a naming convention wherein an uppercase letter denotes a matrix, lowercase a vector, Greek a scalar, and calligraphic uppercase a tensor. With this convention, your first variable is renamed $\:A\to\A$

Next we need the index mapping for flattening a matrix into vector, i.e. $\:\vecc F=f$
$$\eqalign{
F &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \implies
f \in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
F_{ij} &= f_{a} \\
a &= i+(j-1)\,m \\
i &= 1+(a-1)\,{\rm mod}\,m, \quad
j = 1+(a-1)\,{\rm div}\,m \\
}$$
Applying this to the index pairs of a $2k$-order tensor will flattened it to a $k$-order tensor.

Flattening your tensor equation into a matrix equation
admits a general solution
$$\eqalign{
B &= \A:W \qiq b = Aw \\
\\
w &= A^{\bf+}b \;+\; \LR{I-A^{\bf+}A}q \\
  &= A^{\bf+}b \;+\; Pq \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the *double-contraction* product, $A^{\bf+}$ is the pseudoinverse, $P$ is the nullspace projector, and $q$ is an arbitrary vector.

The [Commutation Matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $(K)$ can be used to enforce the symmetry constraint
$$\eqalign{
&\vecc{W} = \vecc{W^T} \doteq K \vecc{W} \\
&w = Kw \\
&\LR{A^+b+Pq} = K\LR{A^+b+Pq} \\
&\CLR{I-K}Pq = \LR{K-I}A^+b \\
&\c{L}Pq = -LA^+b \\
&q = -\LR{LP}^+LA^+b \\
}$$
Substituting this into the previous expression yields
$$\eqalign{
w &= A^+b + Pq \\
 &= A^+b - P\LR{LP}^+LA^+b \qquad\quad \\
 &= \BR{I-P\LR{LP}^+L}\,A^+b \\
}$$
which can be *un-flattened* to recover the $W$ matrix.